# Matplotlib saving blank figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm importing a txt file into a dataframe, and want to make a graph from some of the columns. Whenever I save this its just a blank figure, I'm not using plt.show() which I know can cause issues and I have run test cases without using the dataframe columns with the same problem.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    df=pd.read_csv("filepath", sep= " ",header=None)
    x=df.iloc[:,13]
    y=df.iloc[:,7]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.savefig("Filepath")
```

And this just generates a blank figure, Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can also save the figure after running `plt.plot()` by running `current_fig = plt.gcf()`, and then `current_fig.savefig('current_fig')`.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your code in an Ipython console, but to me it saves fine. What coding environment do you use?

Comment: I'm running in the Spyder IDE, and the method mentioned above does also not work. I have previously saved figures with no problem which is strange.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to save in a directory where the current user doesn't have writing rights? Or a directory that doesn't exist (e.g. due to a typo)?  Or a filename that contains some illegal character?